# Can I remove xterm?

Tags: release-loki

So I typed in my terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xterm
```

and the system then proceeded to uninstall a lot of packages. After the uninstallation was complete I typed xterm and it opened the terminal normally. What was deleted then ? I tried upgrading the system, but nothing was downloaded. Is Xterm essential to the system ? Can I remove it ? How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package manager (`apt`) will not allow you to remove `xterm`. This is there to protect you from yourself. If you attempt to remove it, it'll just install the 32bit package (`xterm:i386`). This is an essential part of an X11 system.

Comment: so I should not be worries about the removed packages right ? They were installed again afterwards ?

Comment: It really depends. I don't know what you removed. I believe, for example, Steam depends on xterm.